# Refactoring T-SQL nested SELECT query to use in a case statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
maker   model   type
B   1121    pc
A   1233    pc
E   1260    pc
A   1752    laptop
A   1276    printer
D   1288    printer
```

I need to receive a result in the form: maker, pc. If a particular maker has models in a given type, I need to concatenate the word 'yes' with the number of models in parentheses. Ex. yes(1) for maker 'A'. So, how can I avoid the following duplication?

```
CASE 
WHEN SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE ... > 0
THEN 'yes(' + CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE ...) AS varchar) + ')'
```

This is not a real world problem. I just need to understand how to save a subquery result to use it in a branch statement. The result of this branch statement may contain the subquery result itself.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: In this example, first I run the query and use the result in a branch expression, then I run the same query to display the result if the condition is matched... I am trying to avoid running the same subquery more than once in a single main query. Ultimate goal is efficiency...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating tables:

```
create table #t (maker varchar(100), model  varchar(100), type varchar(100) );
insert into #t ( maker,   model,   type )  values 
( 'B',   '1121',    'pc'),
( 'A',   '1233',    'pc'),
( 'E',   '1260',    'pc');
```

Query in easy steps:

```
;with 
totals as (
   select maker, type,
       count( * ) as n
   from
       #t
   group by 
      maker,  type
      ) ,
maker_type as (
   select distinct maker, type
   from #t
)
select 
   mm.*, t.n, 
   case  when t.n is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as yes_no
from
   maker_type mm
left outer join
   totals t
      on mm.maker = t.maker and
         mm.type = t.type
```

[Results](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82731?opt.textResults=true):

```
maker type n yes_no 
----- ---- - ------ 
A     pc   1 Yes    
B     pc   1 Yes    
E     pc   1 Yes
```

I don't extend solution concatenating strings because I see that you know how to do it. Be free to change first or second CTE query to match yours requirements.

Comment: Although CTE query can be used only by immediate statement, chaining CTEs will allow next statement to use data from all CTEs in the chain. That's a great feature. Thank you for your example...